# Magento cron or mysql event scheduler which one is best based on perfomance?

Tags: magento2, database, cron, magento-cron

I know in some case we have to run Magento cron as if it is some file or logic base.

But If I just want to perform some task regarding just database like want to update or delete some record from database in this case which one is best based on performance?

Should I create event scheduler in MySQL or Magento cron?

Answer (score 1):

If you interest only in performance the MySql will be a clean winner.

But if maintainability and simplicity of development/deployment matter I will prefer  Magento Crons

Comment: How would an event scheduler perform in a distributed environment?